# Как работает метод peek() в Stream api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

У меня есть следующий код. Объясните, почему в первом вызове метода map() IDEA выделяет его и предлагает заменить на peek(). Я думал что peek() не изменяет сами элементы, но видимо это не так.

```
Map<Timestamp, String> sortedNotes = .....

List<String> nodes = sortedNotes.entrySet().stream().map(el -> {
       Timestamp time = el.getKey();
       String sb = "{\"m\":" + time.getMonth() + ", \"d\":" + time.getDate() + ", \"t\":\"" + el.getValue() +  "\"}";
       el.setValue(sb);
       return el;
}).map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: А покажите какой код будет после замены IDEA

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Предполагается, что `map()` получает на вход один объект, а возвращает другой. Возможно, того же типа, но другой. `peek()` - это частный случай `map()`, который возвращает тот же самый объект, который получил на входе, возможно, с изменённым внутренним состоянием. Конечно, можно использовать для этого `map()`, но есть нюансы. Во-первых, `peek()` на одну строчку короче - не нужно писать `return`, Java и так знает, что нужно возвращать. Во-вторых, вы страхуетесь от ошибок - из `peek()` невозможно вернуть не тот объект, который пришёл на вход. В-третьих, вы даёте подсказку тем, кто читает ваш код: "смотри, тут меняется только внутреннее состояние объекта". Читать такой код становится немного проще. Поэтому IDEA и предлагает замену.

Comment: один из самых толковых ответов, которые я видел про peek()